# Table with Multiple Header Column Span and Footer Total Line

Tags: tables, multicolumn

[[image: Code]][[image: Format]]

I'm having issues formating this table. I have it set out, but i cannot get the `\multicolumn` to span two main headers and a bottom span.

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{.6cm}||p{2.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{2.2cm}||p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c||}{Book Process Guide} & {Price List}\\
 \hline
 Qty &  Type &  Size &  Code &  Dimension &     Each &      Total\\
 \hline
 3 &    Press Pad &     0.055 &  &      8x8 &   2.25 &      6.75\\
 1 &    Release Film &  0.001 &  &      9x9 &    &          0.00\\
 1 &    FR4 &           0.028 &  &      8x8 &   2.00 &      2.00\\
 3 &    Press Pad &     0.055 &  &      8x8 &   2.25 &      6.75\\
 \hline 
 11 &   Books &          &       &       &       &          302.50\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line third as shown below and compile

\multicolumn{5}{|c||}{Book Process Guide} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Price List}\

you will get the desired output.

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! So I fixed the bottom as well, but the word 'Books'  has the text centered when I span it over 4 columns. Is there way to move this text to left align?

Comment: in line mentioned above change the c to l and compile you will get the required result